# execute multiple Runnables from one thread after specified timeout

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I want to schedule Runnables and execute them one after another from the same thread, but not earlier, then, after specified timeout. Is there a standard way of doing it?

here is my code:

```
public class DelayedExecutor {
    private final long           _timeout;
    private final List<Runnable> _tasks = new LinkedList<>();
    private final ThreadFactory  _factory;
    private final Thread         _supervisor;

    public DelayedExecutor(long timeout, ThreadFactory factory) {
        _timeout = timeout;
        _factory = factory;

        _supervisor = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (_supervisor.isInterrupted()) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(_timeout);
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        if (_supervisor.isInterrupted())
                            break;
                    }

                    synchronized (_tasks) {
                        ArrayList<Runnable> prepared = new ArrayList<>(_tasks);
                        Collections.reverse(prepared);

                        execute(prepared);

                        _tasks.clear();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        _supervisor.setDaemon(true);
        _supervisor.start();
    }

    public void schedule(Runnable runnable) {
        synchronized (_tasks) {
            _tasks.add(runnable);
        }
    }

    private void execute(final List<Runnable> tasks) {
        _factory.newThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (Runnable runnable : tasks)
                    runnable.run();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want to execute them sequentially?

Comment: @Lirik yes. but not earlier then timeout (or some other condition). i.e. n runnable are already waiting.

Comment: Take a look at `CountDownLatch`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some nail-biting comments, I think I'm starting to understand what you're doing and it seems like the `Producer`/`Consumer` pattern with a small modification. Based on our chat, I now understand that you want to run the consumer at a fixed rate! This should give you an idea (but use a concurrent collection in your implementation):

```
public FixedRateConsumer implements Runnable
{
    private final object _lock = new object();
    // *** use a concurrent collection here ***
    private Queue<Runnable> _workQueue; 

    public FixedRateConsumer()
    {
        _workQueue = new Queue<Runnable>();
    }

    public scheduleTask(Runnable task)
    {
        synchronized(_lock)
        {
            _workQueue.put(task); 
        }
    }

    public void run()
    {
        synchronized(_lock)
        {
            while(_workQueue.poll()!=null)
            {
                _workQueue.take().run();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And now you just have to schedule the consumer to run at a fixed rate:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
FixedRateConsumer consumer = new FixedRateConsumer();

scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(consumer, /*specify initial delay*/, /*specify rate*/, /*specify TimeUnit*/);
```

Your producer can schedule a task like this:

```
// Then you just schedule your tasks like this
consumer.scheduleTask(new Runnable());
```

Comment: However, one thing to add here is that this is a bit of an anti-pattern... I would recommend you avoid this approach, unless you have a very specific reason why you want to run your consumer at a given rate! Generally, you want to run your consumer "full bore" and have it consume data from the queue, then block if the queue is empty (utilizing the `BlockingQueue`)...

Comment: What language is this? Seems like a cross between Java and C#. :)

Comment: It's a cross between Java and C# :)... doing C# all day and it's hard to break the "habit" when writing in Notepad.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use [ScheduledThreadExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html). You can create it with a pool of one thread:

```
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor exec = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
```

Then look at the `schedule` and `scheduleAtFixedRate` methods.

Comment: if i understand right, ScheduledThreadExecutor can delay execution of a single runnable. what i want to do is to collect several, and execute them all together.

Comment: ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor will run my Runnables as soon as possible.

Comment: No, by using the `schedule` method you can start them after an initial time has elapsed. Look at the javadoc to see what you can do.

Comment: I want to execute all of them, from the single thread but not before timeout. with schedule I can schedule execution with fixed delay only.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create an `ExecutorService` with the threadpool size set to 1 and wait at the end of your `run()` method, or put another `Runnable` that sleeps in it's `run()` into the queue between the Runnables you already have.

Link asked a good question though, as effectively you'll be running those tasks sequentially.

Comment: yes. no problem to run then in a sequence. that's exactly what i want - delay execution of several Runnables, and execute them all together (from the same thread)

Comment: @aav, but in the comment section you said you want to execute them sequentially... running them all together is not sequential, it's concurrent/parallel. Running them from the same thread is not parallel either. :) So which is it? Sequential or Parallel execution?

Comment: @aav, so why do you have concurrency and multi-threading in your tags?

Comment: @Lirik because, executions of my runnables can be scheduled from multiple threads. And there has to be something, in the background, that waits for timeout and triggers execution. I would consider it all concurrency related.

Comment: OK, so you "scheduled" `Runnable`s from multiple threads, but they run sequentially on the same thread that scheduled them? How would you know they timed out? They must be running in parallel to something... what are they running in parallel to? The thread that scheduled them?

Comment: @Lirik multiple threads can schedule them. one specific thread (worker), i.e. provided by a ThreadFactory executes scheduled runnables, from time to time. Obviously, there must be some other "supervisior" thread, which waits for timeout, and initiates execution.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7431/discussion-between-aav-and-lirik)

Comment: OK, so your scheduling is parallel, but your execution is sequential?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run them all at once rather than in sequence then `CountDownLatch` can help.

```
int threads = 10;
final CountDownLatch ready = new CountDownLatch(threads);
final CountDownLatch start = new CountDownLatch(1);
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);
for(int i=1; i<=threads; i++) {
   executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
     ready.countDown();  //Signal that this runnable is ready
     try {
       start.await();  //Wait for the signal
     } catch(InterupptedException e) {}
     Target target = new Target();
     target.doSomeStuff();
    }
   });
}
try {
 ready.await(); //Wait till all are ready
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
}
start.countDown();  //And off they go
```